# Is there any way to get Mr. Mendel to shorten his spiel?

Tags: streetpass-garden-flower-town, streetpass-mii-plaza

Every time I enter the shed in Flower Town, Mr. Mendel goes on and on about how to become a Master Gardener, seed shapes, and what fun going to the mall is.  Is there a way to skip his dialog, or is there anything I can do to give me the short version of his jibber-jabber?

Comment: Obviously, hold "R" to fast forward.  He does shorten his intro as you progress - e.g. once you do a (couple of?) job he doesn't tell you that you should be doing jobs, etc.  Not putting an answer because there may be another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with other SteetPass games, holding R will make the text speed by. Also, as you progress in the game, Mr. Mendel will talk less:

- After completing 2 or 3 jobs satisfactorily, he will stop mentioning that you can do jobs for Ms Bloom.
- After growing a Rare Plant, he'll quit talking about them.
- After you become a Master Gardener, he'll stop talking about that and the journal. I think this is when he finally stops talking about all the shops at the mall, too.

Even after all of this, he will continue to mention one tip each time after your guests enter your courtyard.

Answer (score 0):

mashing A is the only thing i've found that actually speeds things up. it causes the text to complete and then move on.

otherwise. uhm. only play the game if you have enough people visiting to make it worth the endless walls of text.

i really wanna make a game where you get to beat him up for not shutting up.